# How to combine UDIM into one texture?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

I've made a fairly detailed scan using Meshroom that generated 3 maps:

[image: Text]

Then, I've created a remeshed version with new UV's and baked the textures. The result is a bit funky:

[image: Text]

I wonder how to achieve a nice end result with only one texture, instead of those 3 UDIM atlases. I would be grateful beyond measure for your advice after a day of trying to solve that riddle +_+

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could create a new UV map for this mesh, do an unwrap on it, and bake the current visual to that newly created texture map.

For baking you can use the default Blender baking toolset or if don't want to, you could manage this with free Blender add-on called "Principled Baker".